# copy blobs from one storage account to another without overwriting the existing files

Tags: azure

I have to copy the files from one storage account to another and if the file existing in the destination storage account, don't want it to be overwritten instead create an another copy in the destination storage account. I am currently using azcopy sync but it overwrites the files having same name in the destination storage account. Any suggestions to achieve it ?

Comment: please explain what you mean by that and how you see this working?! `instead create an another copy`

Comment: there is a job which runs that take backup of the Source storage account to the backup storage account using azcopy sync. But if in the source storage account a file(FileA) is modified then it gets synced at the backup storage account and overwrites(FileA). So I don't want it to overwrite at the backup storage account instead make a new file

Comment: how about you just turn on blob versioning in your destination account? Otherwise you will need to implement some custom logic that creates that new file (what file name should it get etc.) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/versioning-overview